# jQuery saving checkbox checked status to query string

Tags: jquery, arrays, checkbox, query-string, checked

I'm struggling with understanding Array syntax. I have 6 sets of checkboxes and I'd ideally like to be able to send the responses (checked on = 1 or off = 0) into query strings for parsing on the other side of this form fulfillment.

I've included what I have so far and it works, but I'd prefer to have my URL much shorter and to get there much more efficiently.

Current URL: `http://domain/index.html?t1a=0&t1b=1&t2a=0&t2b0` (imagine this with 30 parameters)

Goal URL: `http://domain/index.html?t1=01&t2=00`

---

HTML sample:

```
<form>
<div id="checkbox-topic1">
    <input name="topic1" class="interest-checkbox" id="topic1a" type="checkbox" />
    <input name="topic1" class="interest-checkbox" id="topic1b" type="checkbox" />
</div>
<div id="checkbox-topic2">
    <input name="topic2" class="interest-checkbox" id="topic2a" type="checkbox" />
    <input name="topic2" class="interest-checkbox" id="topic2b" type="checkbox" />
</div>
</form>
```

JQuery sample:

```
    function appendURLQueryString() {
    var customURL = $("#custom-url");
    // TOPIC 1 ================//
    var t1a = 0;
    if ($('#topic1a').is(':checked')) {
        t1a = 1;
    }
    var t1b = 0;
    if ($('#topic1b').is(':checked')) {
        t1b = 1;
    }
    // TOPIC 2 ================//
    var t2a = 0;
    if ($('#topic2a').is(':checked')) {
        t2a = 1;
    }
    var t2b = 0;
    if ($('#topic2b').is(':checked')) {
        t2b = 1;
    }
    var tempURL = ('http://domain/index.html?t1a=' + t1a + '&t1b=' + t1b + '&t2a=' + t2a + '&t2b=' + t2b);
    customURL.attr("value", tempURL);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: assuming these checkboxes are in a form, have you seen the .serlize() method? http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: thanks, that's a really efficient way to create a query string similar to what I already have, I would ideally like to create a much shorter query string, since I'm up against 30 parameters

Comment: Just curious... Why concatenate the query string? Would a form with POST not work for you?

Comment: The form is posting the data individually as well (sorry my shortened code is misleading). But I'm using the custom URL to redirect the user to a customized results page and to store the concatenated results to send to our sales CRM for contact follow-up.